# How to suscribe a user to an event

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User and a Event model

When the user is on an event page, I would like that he could click a button to say 'Count me in'. Then I could have the list of all participants in that even.

What kind of form I am supposed to write? Do I need another table between ?

```
<%= form_tag concert_path(@concert) do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
 <%= submit_tag "count me in", class:  "btn btn-primary
<% end %>
```

## EDIT

I added the suggested code, but I am facing a no routes matches POST register 
So I added `method: :put`

```
<%= form_tag register_concert_path(@concert), method: :put do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "count me in", class:  "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Now I can add myself to a concert, but something wierd happens, it tries tp downlad a file  `register` and says `Failed - can't find file`

Also How I am supposed to remove the user from the concert? 
Shall i go for a method unsubscribe and remove the current user from the list?

```
def unsubscribe
  concert = Concert.find(params[:id])
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  concert.users.delete(user)
end
```

Comment: can you share the params received in register method?  could you try also the form_for? https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Comment: adding remote true in the form fixed the problem :)

Comment: Could you provide the version that worked for you? For future reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is: [has_and_belongs_to_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)
You need to define the link between concerts and users.

```
class Concert 
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
 has_and_belongs_to_many :concerts
end
```

Then in the controller, please use other action(register), you have to add the user to current concert.

```
def register
  concert = Concert.find(params[id])
  user = User.find(params[user_id])
  concert.users << user # adding the user 
  concert.save
end
```

see the [association reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference)

`routes.rb`

```
resources :concerts do
  member do
    put 'register'
  end
end
```

and the view

```
<%= form_tag register_concert_path(@concert) do %>
 <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>
 <%= submit_tag "count me in", class:  "btn btn-primary
<% end %>
```

Comment: I got it for the association, but I don't know how to create the form

Comment: Thanks a lot I am having an issue with `No route matches [POST] "/concerts/1/register"` I restarted the server

Comment: btw, you don't need to save concert after adding a user

Comment: personally i'd opt for the has_many and then use :through - it allows for the possibility of adding further fields to the join table in the future.